# Alter a file using information from another file

Tags: perl, file, format, alter, phylogeny

I want to alter the names in a phylip file using information from another file. The phylip is just one continuous string of information, and the names I want to alter (e.g. `aaaaaaabyd`) are embedded in it. Like so

```
((aaaaaaabyd:0.23400159127856412500,(((aaaaaaaaxv:0.44910864993667892753,aaaaaaaagf:0.51328033054009691849):0.06090419044604544752,((aaaaaaabyc:0.11709094683204501752,aaaaaaafzz:0.04488198976629347720):0.09529995111708353117,((aaaaaaadbn:0.34408087090010841536,aaaaaaaafj:0.47991503739434709930):0.06859184769990583908,((aaaaaaaabk:0.09244297511609228524,aaaaaaaete:0.12568841555837687030):0.28431
```

(there are no new lines)

The names within are like `aaaaaaaabk`.

The other file has the information change to, like so in the other file,

```
aaaaaaaabk;Ciona savignyi
aaaaaaaete;Homo sapiens
aaaaaaaafj;Cryptosporidium hominis
aaaaaaaaad;Strongylocentrotus purpuratus
aaaaaaabyd;Theileria parva
aaaaaaaaaf;Plasmodium vivax
```

I have tried numerous things but this is the closest I got. The problem is it does it for one and doesn't print out the rest of the phylip file. I need to get to ((Theileria parva:0.23400159127856412500, etc.

```
open(my $tree, "$ARGV[0]") or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
open(my $csv,  "$ARGV[0]") or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
open(my $new_tree, "> raxml_tree.phy");

# Declare variables
my $find;
my $replace;
my $digest;

# put the file of the tree into string variable
my $string = <$tree>;

# open csv file
while (my $line = <$csv>) {

    # aaaaaaaaaa;Ciona savignyi

    if ($line =~ m/(\w+)\;+(\w+\s+\w*)/) {
        $find    = $1;
        $replace = $2;
        $string =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
    }
}
print $new_tree "$string";

close $tree;
close $csv;
close $new_tree;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some guidelines on your own code

- The problem is almost certainly that you are opening the same file `$ARGV[0]` twice. Presumably one should be `$ARGV[1]
- You ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program you write (there is very little point in declaring your variables unless `use strict` is in place) and declare all your variables with `my` as close as possible to their first point of use. It is bad form to declare all your variables in a block at the start, because it makes them all effectively global, and you lose most of the advantages of declaring lexical variables
- You should use the three-parameter form of `open`, and it is a good idea to put the name of the file in the `die` string so that you can see which one failed. So

  ```
  open(my $tree, "$ARGV[0]") or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  open my $tree, '<', $ARGV[0] or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[0]" for input: $!\n};
  ```
- You should look for simpler solutions rather than apply regex methods every time. `$line =~ m/(\w+)\;+(\w+\s+\w*)/` is much tidier as `chomp`, `split /;/`
- You shouldn't use double-quotes around variables when you want just the value of the variable, so `print $new_tree "$string"` should be `print $new_tree $string`

Rather than trying to use the data from the *other file* (please try to use useful names for items in your question, as it's tough to know what to call them when writing a solution) it is best to build a hash that contains all the translations

This program will do as you ask. It builds a regex consisting of an alternation of all the hash keys, and then converts all ocurrences of that pattern into its corresponding name. Only those names that are in your sample *other file* are translated: the others are left as they are

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;  # For non-destructive substitution
use autodie;

my %names;
open my $fh, '<', 'other_file.txt';
while ( <$fh> ) {
  my ($k, $v) = split /;/, s/\s+\z//r;
  $names{$k} = $v;
}

open $fh, '<', 'phylip.txt';
my $data = <$fh>;
close $fh;

my $re = join '|', sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %names;
$re = qr/(?:$re)/;
$data =~ s/\b($re)\b/$names{$1}/g;

print $data;
```

**output**

```
((Theileria parva:0.23400159127856412500,(((aaaaaaaaxv:0.44910864993667892753,aaaaaaaagf:0.51328033054009691849):0.06090419044604544752,((aaaaaaabyc:0.11709094683204501752,aaaaaaafzz:0.04488198976629347720):0.09529995111708353117,((aaaaaaadbn:0.34408087090010841536,Cryptosporidium hominis:0.47991503739434709930):0.06859184769990583908,((Ciona savignyi:0.09244297511609228524,Homo sapiens:0.12568841555837687030):0.28431
```

---

**Update**

Here is a revised version of your own program with the above points accounted for and the bugs fixed

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $tree_fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[0]" for input: $!\n};
my $string = <$tree_fh>;
close $tree_fh;

open my $csv_fh,  '<', $ARGV[1] or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[1]" for input: $!\n};
while ( <$csv_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    my ($find, $replace) = split /;/;
    $string =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
}
close $csv_fh;

open my $new_tree_fh, '>', 'raxml_tree.phy' or die qq{Failed to open "raxml_tree.phy" for output: $!\n};
print $new_tree_fh $string;
close $new_tree_fh;
```